# Making Twilio calls with TwiML in Delphi

Tags: delphi, twilio, indy, twilio-api

I'm using Twilio to call people from a Delphi XE2 application. The calls arrive but I can't seem to use my personal XML as an URL to inform the person I'm calling.

Here is the code:

```
pUrl := 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/' + AccountSid+'/Calls';
AllParams.Add('From=' + PhoneNumberFrom);
AllParams.Add('To=' + pToNumber);
AllParams.Add('Url=' + pXMLUrl);

IdHttp1.Post(pUrl, AllParams)
```

If I use `https://demo.twilio.com/welcome/voice/` as URL it works well. I get the full message and everything. If I use my url from the server it doesn't. 
My XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Response>
 <Say>An urgent ticket has been posted in support portal. Please see to it.</Say>
</Response>
```

Also I've created a TwiML with `HTTPGET` in Twilio Console and if I use `ApplicationSid` instead of `URL` in my application I just get the second sentence when I answer the call.

Would anyone have an idea what is going on?

Comment: Do some debugging. What response do you get?

Comment: I get a good response a proper XML as the call is actually made. Just "Alice" tells me there is an `application error`. Is it perhaps because my url from the server isn't `https` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [your question two hours later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43073711/twilio-call-doesnt-play-the-full-message)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer.

I had to add:

```
AllParams.add('Method=GET')
```

as default method `POST` that is called isn't allowed on static files on IIS.